# Powershell Windows Forms onClick event

Tags: winforms, powershell, get-eventlog

I have a Windows forms (in PowerShell), and the form has a button with onclick event but the command in the onclick isn't run. I don't know why, because it can be run sepratley. My sciptblock is here:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Width = 500
$form.Height = 200
$form.formborderstyle = 3
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Text = "Search"
$button1.Height = 25
$button1.Width = 85
$button1.Top = 100
$button1.Left = 25
$button1_OnClick = 
    {
        Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After $a2.Value.Date | Where-Object 
{$_.EventID -eq "4800" -or $_.EventID -eq "4801"} | Format-Table
    }
$button1.add_Click($button1_OnClick)
$form.Controls.Add($button1)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Please help to resolv my problem. 
Thanks advance!

Comment: You didnt define $A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things

You did not define **$a** in

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After $a2.Value.Date
```

Second you didnt decide how to output the table. You can do something like...

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After $a2.Value.Date | Where-Object{$_.EventID -eq "4800" -or $_.EventID -eq "4801"} | Format-Table | Out-Host
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake to show my $a definition, but your answare was good for me with the | Out-Host pipeline! Thanks a lot ArcSet!